# Newer Threejs version and mouse over

Tags: three.js

Im trying to use last threejs version to load a Collada Loader. Furthermore, I just want to make a mouse over events.

I've been reading (and analyzing a lot of examples) about this on related forum, there is a problem about intersectObjects (this function makes possible mouse over evet).

Question is simple: How can I code mouse over events on pieces of my model?

[Here is my example](http://webgl.drapps.info/) but It is not using the latest version of the threejs library.

Nothing else at the moment, I think It is so hard to begin with this library, there isn't so much documentation...

My root issue is when mouse is out of canvas, threejs detects mouse over some piece of my model and through the event... I think if I update threejs this may be fixed

Thank you!!!

Comment: Have you tried `mousedown` event to check whether it works or not ?

Comment: I dont understand you...

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see you already implemented intersectObjects.Try using this on your canvas:

`position : absolute,
top : 0px`

Seems to me that you dont use the right mousePosition for the calculation. Try using the relative mousePosition of the canvas and not of the document. And I would not check for intersection on every render call. Maybe on a mouseMove event or on an interval.

Comment: Yes, in example Im using intersectObjects because Im not using latest version... how can I control mouse over events with latest version of threejs (wich doesn't have intersectObjects function?)